# rounding values in a dataframe and losing the decimal point

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to round the values of a pandas dataframe to the nearest integer so that I can save the dataframe down this way before potentially reading / saving it into a csv. I am not sure why I cannot match the results depicted on the pandas website for the .round() method. Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

x1 = np.random.randn(10)
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'x':x1})

df1

    x
0   0.540351
1   0.205924
2   0.619970
3   0.636680
4   -1.415081
5   0.162028
6   -0.080224
7   -0.022692
8   -0.367687
9   -0.365140

df1.round(0)

    x
0   1.0
1   0.0
2   1.0
3   1.0
4   -1.0
5   0.0
6   0.0
7   0.0
8   0.0
9   0.0
```

i would like to obtain "1" and "0" - this is what i would expect based on the online docs - https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.round.html. the third example where .round(decimals) is shown gives "1" and "0" to column B, as opposed to 1.0 and 0.0.

Comment: I see what you mean regarding series B in the docs. I cannot reproduce what the docs have in Pandas v0.23. However, since it's not documented in words one way or another, I would not rely on any implicit dtype conversion.

Answer (score 1):

[`pd.Series.round`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.round.html) with argument 0 is doing its job by rounding to 0 decimal places. No conversion to integer dtype is promised. To make sure this happens, you should apply the conversion in a separate step:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)

x1 = np.random.randn(10)
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'x':x1})

print(df1['x'].round(0).astype(int))

0    2
1    0
2    1
3    2
4    2
5   -1
6    1
7    0
8    0
9    0
Name: x, dtype: int32
```

Answer (score 0):

You can using `format`

```
df.x.map("{:.0f}".format).astype(int)
Out[471]: 
0    1
1    0
2    1
3    1
4   -1
5    0
6    0
7    0
8    0
9    0
Name: x, dtype: int32
```